# Google auth using react. How to realise it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to implement google auth in react. I have button that redirects user to google authentification form. After user logged in his account he is redirected back to my app where I need to catch the code and send it to backend to get token.

Here is what I mean by code. It is the code part in the url lower:

https://url/?code=4%2FSgFDF46lgpVT1EPdWnYNprlD5c2Meq9h2gc_mYmB5SSdwdgc339X5NwKgBxa6fqz7j-MIMcTaGyhIV6MjnF1_Ec&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile#

The question is how do I catch this code and save it to send to backend?

Comment: the link does not work

Comment: Are you using firebase for authentication?

Comment: Is this the link that Google returns after successful authentication?